# How to test bugs in ray picking in three.js?

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, 3d, three.js, webgl

I am trying to implement ray picking for mesh files in three.js. I am adapting from these two examples:

http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes.html
http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes.html

Which contain essentially identical, and simple approaches to ray casting. I am implementing this in almost the exact same way, except that I use trackball controls for my camera controls.

The problem is that the system gives both false positives and false negatives. I have tried drawing the lines that come from this, and it seems that the lines are always going in unanticipated directions toward a similar destination.

```
function testfunction(event){ 

    // I devide by 3.5 and 2 respectively, because I do this with the actual 
    //rendering window so that it doesn't take up the entire screen. 
    //Omitting the division doesn'tseem to change the behavior too much 

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / (window.innerWidth / 3.5) ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / ( window.innerHeight / 2) ) * 2 + 1, 0.5 );

    // Line to visualize the supposed position of our raycaster. 
    //I may be doing this wrong, but it seems that the  
    // line is coming and going from the wrong position. 
    var material2 = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x0000ff
        });

    var geometry2 = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry2.vertices.push( camera.position);
    geometry2.vertices.push(vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize());


    var line = new THREE.Line(geometry2, material2);
     scene.add(line);
    //unprojects the vector is per most picking alogorithms. 
    //I don't know the math to check if this is the correct value.          

    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( mesh, true );

    console.log("Intersection length:" + intersects.length);

    //Arrow was suggested to me. It points up from the origin? wth? 
    var arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper(  camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize());
    scene.add(arrow);
    console.log(arrow);

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) { 
    // getting both false positives and negatives. However, I am implementing this exactly as Mr. Doob does. 
    // Could it be the trackball controls I am using that are screwing this up? 

    console.log("win!"); 

    }else{

    console.log("fail");

    }
```

I am sure I am doing something dumb here, so I beg your pardon for such a banal question. 
Why am I getting false positives?
Is my approach flawed somehow?

Comment: If it helps, from what I observe through the lines that I am drawing, the rays do not appear to be shooting out parallel to the camera into the world, they appear to be going to a central point just behind my model.

Comment: It seems that I was subtracting with the vector argument twice. Cloning the vector for the test fixed the problem. I shall answer my own question when given the opportunity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my debugging tests:

```
 var geometry2 = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry2.vertices.push( camera.position);
    geometry2.vertices.push(vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize());
```

did the subtraction operation twice.

Answer (score 0):

> "I divide by 3.5 and 2 respectively, because I do this with the actual rendering window so that it doesn't take up the entire screen."

The following is a code block from the editor that performs picking. If you substitute your 3.5 and 2.0 constants and use `element.getBoundingClientRect()`, does that positively affect the outcome?

```
var getIntersects = function ( event, object ) {

    var rect = container.dom.getBoundingClientRect();
    x = (event.clientX - rect.left) / rect.width;
    y = (event.clientY - rect.top) / rect.height;
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( ( x ) * 2 - 1, - ( y ) * 2 + 1, 0.5 );

    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

    ray.set( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

    if ( object instanceof Array ) {

        return ray.intersectObjects( object );

    }

    return ray.intersectObject( object );
};
```

Comment: Same exact result.Thanks for the helpful tip, though.